# Self-appointed Olympic judges (non-objective scoring by questioners)

Tags: discussion

This admittedly popular and amusing question [Coding in song - Representing music lyrics in a programming language of your choosing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/coding-in-song-representing-music-lyrics-in-a-programming-language-of-your-cho) is unfolding in an unusual manner.

To me, the crux of the problem is that the question doesn't define any objective winning criteria. Essentially, the questioner has self-appointed emself as the Olympic judge who comes along after you answer to rate and score your answer.

If it were a popularity contest, then the objectivity would be "the will of the community rules" and it would be judged on upvotes. Since it is not a popularity contest, I believe it requires objective winning criteria or it is not a valid question.

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, 2012 is over and someone posted a really late answer. Except if the question starts to get more activity, I don't think that this would be problem.

Comment: Yeah, in the case of that question, the ship has sailed. I'm just curious where we are on general policy about that kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wryly humorous that the poster of that question never selected a winner anyway, but it's clear that by current standards it's off-topic, and since StackExchange praxis in general seems to be that off-topic questions which draw attention to themselves by attracting new answers are closed, I have voted to close it.